# Right side of my RichFaces pickList not populating with default values

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I was wondering if anyone could please help. I am experiencing a challenge. When I do something like this in my backing bean it works fine:

```
private String [] testRight;

private String [] testLeft; (with getters and setters)

public void initalizeLeftRightSide2()

    {

        this.testLeft = new String[5];

        this.testRight = new String[2];

        testLeft[0] = "module1";

        testLeft[1] = "module2";

        testLeft[2] = "module3";

        testLeft[3] = "module4";

        testLeft[4] = "module5";



        testRight[0] = "module2";

        testRight[1] = "module4";

    }
```

But when I do it with my Module objects the right side does not get populated:

```
private List<Modules> allModules;

private List<Modules> forSelectedRole;

public void initalizeLeftRightSide3(Long selectedRoleID)

    {

         this.allModules = modRole.getAllModules();

        Roles theRole = modRole.getModuleListByRoleID(selectedRoleID);

        this.forSelectedRole = theRole.getModulesLst();

    }
```

My JSF to initialize the pickList is this with a converter implemented:

```
<rich:pickList  value="#{addModuleToRole.forSelectedRole}" sourceCaption="Available Modules" targetCaption="Selected Modules" listWidth="200px" listHeight="200px" >

                       <f:selectItems value="#{addModuleToRole.allModules}" var="moules" itemValue="#{moules}" itemLabel="#{moules.name}" />

                   <f:converter converterId="modulesConverter" />                      

</rich:pickList>
```

Just to add forSelectedRole is a subset of allModules.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Further to Vasil's comment, I am calling the initalizeLeftRightSide3(rSelected) method as the second stage in a process of updating modules attached to a particular role. The 1st stage is for the user to select the role to be updated which then submits to the following code.

public void processAddModule2Role()
    {

```
    //First get the role selected
    Long rSelected = Long.parseLong(getSelectedRole());

    initalizeLeftRightSide3(rSelected);

    //redirect to addModuleToRole2.xhtml which contains the pickList
    sh.redirect2("/pages/admin/rolemgmt/addModuleToRole2.xhtml");   
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Check if/when you call `initalizeLeftRightSide3`. Try `<f:selectItems value="#{addModuleToRole.allModules}" />.

Comment: Thanks for response Vasil. I tried your suggestion and the system prints out its representation of the Module object rather than the Module name while nothing shows on the right hand side.

Comment: You need created method `public List<SelectItem> getModulesForRole()` instead of `List<Modules>`